# PostgreSQL 9.3.5 difference from 8.3.6 when extracting epoch from casted value

Tags: timestamp, postgresql-9.3

We've got a table which contains a timestamp as a string, and have been retrieving its epoch on a PostgreSQL 8.3.6 server using *extract*:

```
select '2015/01/07 14:00:00' as the_timestamp, 
extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp)) as the_epoch;

    the_timestamp    | the_epoch
---------------------+------------
 2015/01/07 14:00:00 | 1420668000
(1 row)
```

We're finally upgrading, and have a server running PostgreSQL 9.3.5, and are now getting a different result:

```
select '2015/01/07 14:00:00' as the_timestamp, 
extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp)) as the_epoch;

    the_timestamp    | the_epoch
---------------------+------------
 2015/01/07 14:00:00 | 1420639200         <<=== this is 8 hours earlier
(1 row)
```

Both of these examples are using *psql* as the client, both are using the same timezone:

```
show timezone;

      TimeZone
---------------------
 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```

In the PostgreSQL [9.3 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html), I found this:

> NOTE: The SQL standard requires that writing just *timestamp* be
>   equivalent to *timestamp without time zone*, and PostgreSQL honors that
>   behavior. (Releases prior to 7.3 treated it as *timestamp with time
>   zone*.) *timestamptz* is accepted as an abbreviation for *timestamp with
>   time zone*; this is a PostgreSQL extension.

I found that if I change the query to use *timestamptz* on the 9.3 server, it gives the same result as 8.3:

```
select '2015/01/07 14:00:00' as the_timestamp, 
extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp)) as the_epoch;

    the_timestamp    | the_epoch
---------------------+------------
 2015/01/07 14:00:00 | 1420668000
(1 row)
```

Note that both *timestamp* and *timestamptz* give the same results on 8.3:

```
select extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamptz));
 date_part
------------
 1420668000
(1 row)

select extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp));
 date_part
------------
 1420668000
(1 row)
```

Seems like we found a bug in 9.3?  It seems that extracting this way is incorrectly assuming *with time zone* when it should not.

Comment: Do you mean a bug in 8.3?

Comment: I'm thinking 9.3 isn't handling the extract of a "timestamp" cast correctly.  It seems to be treating it as "timestamp WITH time zone" instead of "timestamp WITHOUT time zone" which the documentation says should be the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` does not mean what you think it means. Unfortunately it doesn't mean "take this timestamp and store it, along with the associated time zone, as two separate values in a field". Instead it's treated by PostgreSQL as "take this timestamp, which you should assume is in local time unless it has a timezone specifier, and convert it to UTC, then store it as UTC. Convert it back to local time for display."

The timezone information is actually used then discarded on import, making `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` a horrible misnomer.

The issue you're having is that the epoch for `timestamp with time zone` is the *UTC*, not local time, epoch. Because the timestamp is assumed to be in local time unless you specify a time zone specifier this means that TimeZone affects the interpretation of the input.

### Details

When you write:

```
cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp)
```

or the equivalent for a literal:

```
TIMESTAMP '2015/01/07 14:00:00'
```

you're saying "the timestamp '2015/01/07 14:00:00' as a point in wall-clock time with no time zone defined." The local TimeZone doesn't affect it. The epoch is assumed to be in the same time zone as the timestamp, whatever that is. Which is why setting TimeZone has no effect on it:

```
regress=# SET TimeZone = 'Australia/Perth';
SET
regress=# SELECT extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp));
 date_part  
------------
 1420639200
(1 row)

regress=# SET TimeZone = UTC;
SET
regress=# SELECT extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp));
 date_part  
------------
 1420639200
(1 row)
```

Now, when you instead use `timestamp with time zone` you're saying that the timestamp is in local time unless it specifies otherwise. It will be imported and converted to UTC for internal storage. Then it's converted back to local time, as defined by TimeZone, for display/output.

The epoch is UTC, not local time.

Which is why this happens:

```
regress=# SET TimeZone = 'Australia/Perth';
SET
regress=# SELECT extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp with time zone));
 date_part  
------------
 1420610400
(1 row)

regress=# SET TimeZone = UTC;
SET
regress=# SELECT extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp with time zone));
 date_part  
------------
 1420639200
(1 row)
```

The reason the `extract` result is different is because *the input timestamp value is different*. It's the same value, but the TimeZone is considered when reading and loading the value. It makes more sense if you look at it in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE myts (ts timestamp without time zone, tstz timestamp with time zone);

SET TimeZone = UTC;
INSERT INTO myts(ts,tstz) VALUES ('2015/01/07 14:00:00','2015/01/07 14:00:00');
SET TimeZone = 'Australia/Perth';
INSERT INTO myts(ts,tstz) VALUES ('2015/01/07 14:00:00','2015/01/07 14:00:00');
```

now look at the contents:

```
regress=# Set TimeZone = UTC;
SET
regress=# SELECT * FROM myts;
         ts          |          tstz          
---------------------+------------------------
 2015-01-07 14:00:00 | 2015-01-07 14:00:00+00
 2015-01-07 14:00:00 | 2015-01-07 06:00:00+00
(2 rows)
```

and the epochs:

```
regress=# SELECT extract(epoch from ts) as ets, extract(epoch from tstz) as etstz FROM myts;
    ets     |   etstz    
------------+------------
 1420639200 | 1420639200
 1420639200 | 1420610400
(2 rows)
```

As you can see it's the *input* that's affecting things, not the output.

### What about with explicit time zones?

Now, what if we set an explicit time zone in the input?

```
SET TimeZone = UTC;

INSERT INTO myts(ts,tstz) VALUES ('2015/01/07 14:00:00 +8','2015/01/07 14:00:00 +8');
```

You'll see that the effect is the same as if TimeZone was set to `Australia/Perth`, i.e. the local TimeZone setting is ignored for input because the timestamp contains an explicit timezone.

This still yields different epochs for timestamp with and without time zone though. The time zone qualifier is *discarded* from the `timestamp` field, wheras it's used to *convert* the `timstamptz` field.

(Yes, the fact that time zones on `timestamp` get discarded is horrid. There are many horrid things about SQL times.)

### So how do you get the desired result?

Use `timestamp` if you want local times, not points in universal time.

Alternately, tell PostgreSQL you want the epoch of the timestamptz without conversion back to local time, i.e. in UTC, by reinterpreting it as a timestamp in UTC using the `AT TIME ZONE` operator:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from cast('2015/01/07 14:00:00' as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
```

Or just run your server with TimeZone set to `UTC`. Frankly this is what most people do, as the semantics of `TimeZone` and `timestamp` vs `timestamptz` just aren't very useful most of the time.

### why is 8.3 different?

No idea, I'd have to dig through way more release notes and commit logs than I have time for. It looks like `timstamptz` input was changed to respect `TimeZone` but I don't know when or what the exact rationale was at the time.

Comment: Thanks Craig for your time in explaining this so clearly.  Your examples need to be in the PostgreSQL documentation.